# Jest doesn't load environment variables (even with --setupFiles dotenv/config)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, dotenv

I'm writing tests for my Express project, but when I run the test script my environment variables are not loaded.

In other threads people suggested using `--setupFiles dotenv/config`, which I did, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried both adding it to my test script and to a `jest.config.js` file, but none worked. Does someone have any hint on how to fix this?

**Context**

This is how I setup jest on `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --setupFiles dotenv/config"
  },
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
},
```

At the top of my `app.js` file, I load my environment variables with
`require('dotenv').config();`

And this is my folder structure:

[image: project's folder structure: a source folder with several folders inside it, including a test folder. Outside src are app.js, routes.js, .env, package.json and some other files]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by moving `.env` file from the `src/` folder to the root folder.

Comment: I already have it in my root folder. What should be done for this case?

Comment: @Allan Juan, This works perfectly fine, is there any solution for dotenv to pickup .env file anywhere in the project structure, like in my case it is present in src/

Comment: You can use the path argument, like this: `require('dotenv').config({ path: 'src/.env' })`. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/tree/master/server). It [uses](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/blob/master/server/package.json) both [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) and [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to pass env variables to Express:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r dotenv/config ./build/srv/main.js
```

Alternatively the sibling [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/tree/master/server) uses cross-env only.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the above 'crisp' projects.

Comment: Isn't crossenv intended to fix platform compatibility problems? Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just not seeing how this could help. The env variables are being loaded when I run the server, they are not loaded only when I run tests.

Comment: This entry (from the `scripts` section of `package.json`): `"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest"` will load env variable(s) only when you run tests by executing `yarn test`.